# Cognos Data Manager to Cognos Datastage Migration

Tags: migration, datastage

I'm looking at a migration project to migrate a client from Datamanager to Datastage.  I can see that IBM have helpfully added in the Migration Assistant tool, but less helpfully, I cannot find any details on how to actually use it.

I did use it some years ago, and I'm aware that you need to do it in a command line interface and it works by taking an extract file and creating a Datastage job out of it, which is then reinstalled.  However I haven't got my notes any more from that process.

If there is a user guide out there for this tool, I'd love to see it.

Cheers

JK

Answer (score 0):

Your starting point would be [the IBM support page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/migrating-ibm-cognos-data-manager-infosphere-datastage) and then see "How to download the tool" and ensure you have the required version (10.2.1 + Fix Pack 13 + Interim Fix) installed. The user guide PDF is part of the install in the sub-folder "datamanager/migration".